Determine why one MAUI project builds and another one doesn't
I have a MAUI project created from the DevExpress maui-dx dotnet project template, using just the --product grid template option for the DevExpress DataGridView control. This project was building with a content page that used a simple DevExpress DataGridView control. Then I added DataGridView.AdvancedColumnLayout markup to that control, and now the project is no longer building, with the error:
Error XFC0000 XamlC: Cannot resolve type "clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.DataGrid;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.DataGrid:dxg:AdvancedColumnLayout.RowDefinitions"


I added the DevExpress example project for Advanced Column Layout to my solution, and the example project builds fine, with the same ``DataGridView.AdvancedColumnLayout` type markup that is causing my own project to fail. Comparing my project and the example project with Beyond Compare shows that both projects the same, so I thought maybe a NuGet restore was needed on my project, but that didn't help.
Now I'm trying to learn where to look for possible differences between these two projects that aren't apparent, even when directly, side by side, comparing the two .csproj files. All I have to go on is Rider's build output from my project, that shows two calls to csc.exe, with command lines that are each 30kb long. Please note that I know I shouldn't be calling the compiler directly, but I didn't set this up and I didn't know these calls were being made until now.
Please note that I'm not asking how to fix this problem but rather, what can I look at to determine what is different in the build setup for these two projects? This issue has highlighted a shortcoming in my understanding of the dotnet build process and tooling and I am trying to address that by solving a real world problem.

I've never seen a clr-namespace declaration with a colon in the assembly - are you sure that's correct?

@Jason, Thanks for pointing that out, I completely overlooked that because my project was building to start with, and I didn't think I had changed the namespace when I added the advanced column layout.
